# Run Time Error when copying ChartObjects in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the creation of some charts in excel using VBA.

I'm using the following code:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim cRow As Long, currentRow As Long, endRow As Long, coutner As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    cRow = 2
    
    While ws1.Cells(cRow, 28).Value <> ""
        currentRow = cRow
        counter = 0
        
        While ws1.Cells(currentRow, 28).Value = ws1.Cells(cRow, 28).Value
            counter = counter + 1
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Wend
        counter = counter - 1
        
        ws1.ChartObjects("Dummy Diagramm").Copy
        
        ws2.Paste
        
        ' Do Stuff with the new Chart

        cRow = cRow + counter + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

When this Makro has to handel 4 or less Charts, it works without a problem. But as soon as more than 4 Charts are created, the Makro crashes and I get a Runtime-Error (Run Time Error '1004': Paste Method Of worksheet Class Failed error).
When I try to debug the makro and go through it step by step, the makro does not run into an error.

Anybody else noticed this behaviour and maybe has an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Try adding `DoEvents` between `Copy` and `Paste`, sometimes it helps with unexpected clipboard problems.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do the trick... it is really unconsitent aswell... sometime it works for 3, then for 6 Charts... strange

Comment: This is a problem. Sometimes `DoEvents` helps, sometimes you need a couple `DoEvents` in a row. This makes me a little crazy sometimes sometines.